# Different kind of PlotStyle in ListPlot

Tags: plotting

Say I have a dataset.

```
data={{1,2},{3,4},{5,6},{7,8},{9,10}}
ListPlot[data, Joined->True,PlotStyle->Dashed]
```

I can change the plotstyle with `DotDashed`instead of `Dashed`.
 What are the other options available? Can I make it a line made of  *
 or ~.

Comment: Look at documentation for [`Dashing`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dashing.html) or [`AbsoluteDashing`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsoluteDashing.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}, {9, 10}};

{xmin, xmax} = MinMax[data[[All, 1]]];

Manipulate[
 pts = Interpolation[data][#] & /@ 
   Range[xmin, xmax, (xmax - xmin)/n];
 ListPlot[{pts, data},
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red},
  PlotMarkers -> marker,
  DataRange -> {xmin, xmax}],
 Row[{
   Control[{{n, 20}, Range[20, 50, 5]}],
   Spacer[25],
   Control[{{marker, "*"}, {"~", "@", "#", "$", "%", "&", "*"}}]}]]
```

[image]